Seeking Help on Power Analysis for Multilevel Model in R
I'm planning to perform a power analysis for a multilevel model in R, focusing on both individual (Level 1) and team levels (Level 2). Our model is complex, involving a mediated moderation effect with the independent variable, mediator, and dependent variable at Level 2, and a Level 1 moderator affecting the mediator-dependent variable relationship.
The goal of this power analysis is to estimate the necessary sample size at both levels to achieve sufficient statistical power. We intend to gather data from leaders and their immediate followers to examine the team-level effect. I'm seeking advice on determining the optimal number of teams (leaders) and the required number of followers per team for our study.
Below is my current code, which I believe has errors. I would greatly appreciate any practical advice or corrections.
##POWER ANALYSIS FOR MODIFIED MODEL - Mediator: Supervisor's performance rating
##All variables on a 5-point Likert scale

#Step 1: Install and Load Necessary Packages
#if (!requireNamespace("brms", quietly = TRUE)) install.packages("brms")
#if (!requireNamespace("future.apply", quietly = TRUE)) install.packages("future.apply")
library(brms)
library(future.apply)

#Step 2: Define Simulation Function
simulate_power <- function(n_teams) {
  set.seed(NULL)  # Ensures each simulation is different
  
  # Simulating data on a 5-point Likert scale
  teamID <- 1:n_teams
  X <- sample(1:5, n_teams, replace = TRUE)  # Team input variable
  W <- sample(1:5, n_teams, replace = TRUE)  # Individual-level variable
  M <- sample(1:5, n_teams, replace = TRUE)  # Supervisor's rating of team performance
  Y <- sample(1:5, n_teams, replace = TRUE)  # Outcome variable
  
  data_sim <- data.frame(teamID, X, M, Y, W)
  
  # Fit the model using brms
  fit <- brm(Y ~ X + W + M + (1 | teamID), data = data_sim, family = categorical(), chains = 2, iter = 2000, warmup = 500, 
             control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95), refresh = 0, silent = TRUE)
  
  # Extract summary
  summary_fit <- summary(fit)
  
  # Check if 95% CI for the effect of X excludes zero
  effect_X <- summary_fit$fixed["X",]
  power <- ifelse(effect_X["l-95% CI"] > 0 | effect_X["u-95% CI"] < 0, 1, 0)
  
  return(power)
}

#Step 3: Determine Sample Size Range
#Step 4: Run Simulations Across Sample Sizes
# Setup parallel processing
plan(multisession)

# Define ranges of sample sizes to test
n_teams_range <- seq(40, 160, by = 20)

# Run simulations
results <- future_sapply(n_teams_range, function(n_teams) {
  mean(replicate(30, simulate_power(n_teams)))  # Replicate each scenario 30 times
})

names(results) <- paste("Teams:", n_teams_range)
print(results)

#Step 5: Evaluate Results
##The output results will give you the proportion of simulations 
##(for each team size) where the effect of interest was detected with 
##sufficient precision. Look for the smallest team size where 
##this proportion (power) meets your desired threshold (commonly 0.80 or 0.85).

